# windows single sign on tomcat through IIS Url rewrite

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, single-sign-on, waffle

I'm facing a difficult setup where I have to configure single sign on, based on the logged in used on my tomcat application.
I already took some steps which allow me to login via single sign on directly on my tomcat application by using waffle.

I have 1 server where I have a tomcat running and a IIS running (but this IIS will move to another server in the same domain in the future).
I have the Tomcat running on port 8205 and the IIS configure to accept url's from authpoc.company.com. IIS does a redirect to localhost:8025 via URL Rewrite. 
My web.xml from IIS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8205/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**What works**

- When opening the application directly on localhost:8205 on the server. I get a nice single sign on based on my domain user.
- When opening the application directly on the ip of the server. 192.168.1.1:8205. I can log in but single sign on does not work anymore. This I don't understand. (edit: solved, this is a setting in Internet explorer, see [SSO waffle asking username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675335/sso-waffle-asking-username-and-password) for more information)

**What doesn't work**

- When redirecting from IIS, I don't get to login into my tomcat application. I have windows authentication enabled, with Negotiate and NTML enabled (in this sequence).

I read a lot on the internet but I can't find anyone with this particular setup. I don't really have the impression I'm doing something exotic.
One possiblity is that I should connect IIS via AJP instead of a much simpeler URL rewrite.

any help is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on the google groups saying this is not possible because of the reverse proxy counting as a hop.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/waffle-users/VCaawJMD0Mw

I'm going to try another approach